# setting up swagger 3 or OpenAPI in a gradle springboot api

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, openapi-generator

Swagger 3 ? or Open API ..? 3? not sure what they're calling it. There doesn't seem to be a good or easy setup.

I'm looking to add it to my java project
I don't mind manually filling out the config for my controllers and in fact do not want it dynamically config'd
and I don't want a lot of extra fluff with it.

Their github hosts a number of different files and I'm not sure what I do and don't need.

The setup at:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/development/setting-up.md

I've run through the setup commands and started locally which returns 2 js files, 1 css, and the swagger.json.

Does anyone know if there's a gradle or maven import / line that I can just plop into my build and get the code I need?

Has anyone setup swagger 3 with just the bare minimum to host the ui page with their controller on a java/springboot app?

any help welcome.

git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui.git
cd swagger-ui
npm install
npm run dev

Comment: Since you use Java you probably need [Springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/) or [Swagger Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Getting-started).

Comment: so that's swagger 2 @helen